# Wrong redirection Uri with Google OAuth2

Tags: php, symfony, google-api-php-client

I have been working in a web Symfony app that uses a google oauth2. Well, to use it I had to create a Client and a Secret id for development environtment.

The redirection uri is:

```
http://melomaniacs.com/app_dev.php/validate/
```

and it is working properly.
When I finish and put on a EC2 instance, I created a new Client an Secret id for a production environment and set them properly on parameters, and the uri is:

```
http://www.melomaniacsweb.com/validate/
```

The problem is google is redirecting to the dev one uri, not the new one.

I tried: 
`php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod`
clearing the browser cache

Anybody know why this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solves by clearing cache without warmup first:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug --no-warmup

php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod
```